# Ordenar resultados timestamp apenas pelo tempo?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de ranking de tempo de um jogo. O jogo usa tempo UNIX como medida de tempo. Preciso colocar os menores tempos primeiro em ordem crescente, porém como o tempo UNIX inclui data também, o tempo é calculado também pela data. Sendo assim, os registros mais recentes acabam ficando na frente do ranking devido a sua data.

Existe alguma forma de ordenar os resultados da busca apenas pelo tempo, descartando a data?

Minhas *queries* no MySQL foram as seguintes:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM challenge, guild, mapnames WHERE challenge.GuildID = guild.guildid AND challenge.MapID = mapnames.mapid ORDER BY challenge.RecordTime ASC";
```

e depois, ao pesquisar na internet, dessa maneira. Ainda sem sucesso.

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM challenge, guild, mapnames WHERE challenge.GuildID = guild.guildid AND challenge.MapID = mapnames.mapid ORDER BY date ASC";
```

No PHP, para mostrar o resultado, usei o date como meio pra formatar o tempo UNIX para tempo humano:

```
"<td>", date("H:i:s", $row['RecordTime']) . "</td>",
```

Comment: Está difícil entender seu problema. Se os timestamps são de dias diferentes não seria obrigatório também considerar os dias? Ou talvez você não esteja se referindo à duração do jogo?

Comment: Eu gostaria de considerar apenas o tempo, sem os dias. Os resultados dos timestamps vão pra uma coluna de uma tabela no mysql e são alimentados por um aplicativo terceiro (Estou tentando montar um servidor de WOW) então não tenho como mudar isso. Quando um challenge é finalizado, o tempo de duração é registrado em timestamp, os menores tempos devem aparecer no topo do ranking.

Comment: Tempo é um vetor puntiforme e não um escalar. Você tem que ter duas data para medir o tamanho dum vetor temporal, a data inicial da medição e a data final da medição. O módulo da subtração entre as datas final e inicial da medição temporal é equivalente ao tempo gasto por um evento que esse sim é um escalar comparável. Como tempo transcorre de forma linear ao futuro normalmente o cálculo do módulo é desprezado e só é feita a subtração entre as medições temporais.

Answer (score 1):

Com base no problema proposto, creio que possa ser resolvido com as funções abaixo:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),'%H:%i:%s')
```

Resultado:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM challenge, guild, mapnames WHERE challenge.GuildID = guild.guildid AND challenge.MapID = mapnames.mapid ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(challenge.RecordTime),'%H:%i:%s') ASC";
```

Referências:

- https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php
- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp